# Can we create a Firewall application for iPhone (iOS 4.x)

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am looking for intercepting all TCP traffic on iPhone (iOS 4.x). I have searched on iOS Developer Library but could not find anything.

I want to create a standalone application that would run in background (as Firewall). This application should intercept all TCP traffic, no matter which application has initiated it (Safari, Mail etc.). Is it possible on iPhone?

On iPhone can we somehow redirect all network traffic to Loopback-URL (localhost)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not even slightly possible on a normal iPhone, sorry!

It might be possible if it's jailbroken but even then, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is possible on JB devices and as a matter of fact they already released on Cydia an app called Firewall iP by Yllier and it does the job great with all TCP and UDP communication.